# How to export an opencv object to disk in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to export opencv's bag of words image descriptor extractor object (cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor) to disk. I've tried opencv's FileStorage class and cPickle, but none of them worked.

This is the code I used to create the object :

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
bowDiction = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(sift, cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
```

Then used FileStorage class from opencv:

```
f = cv2.FileStorage('test.yml',flags=1)
f.write(name='bowDict',val=bowDiction)
f.release()
```

this returned an error saying :

```
TypeError: val is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

When I tried to use cPickle to pickle the object, it returned:

```
TypeError: can't pickle cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor objects
```

I've looked through many sources but didn't find anything conclusive, so is there a proper documented way to store this object?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a BOWExtractor object is quick, so maybe it's not neccessary to store it.
But get vocabulary from BOW Kmeans trainer cluster takes time. So maybe we can store the vocabulary once we get it, and load it to setVocabulary for BOWExtractor